# Pyarrow from_pandas crashes the interpreter when a dataframe contains mixed dtypes

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow

Using *pyarrow 0.6.0* (or inferior), the following snippet causes the Python interpreter to crash:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, True]})
pa.Table.from_pandas(data)
```

"The Python interpreter has stopped working" (under windows)

Comment: In the future, it's usually not a good practice to report issues about old versions of an open source project. There have been 2 releases of pyarrow since 0.6.0: 0.7.0 and 0.7.1.

Comment: @WesMcKinney I would agree on that in most cases, however finding the cause of a crash and its fix can take a lot of time (no log of an error whatsoever) can take a lot of time, and I believe a quick post like this one might help save some time. Bear in mind that the example above is not the code I had to debug to find out that the issue came from there and that the fix exists in a later version

Comment: Right, but in these cases, the first step in debugging should be `conda update pyarrow` (or `pip install -U`). We are not yet at a stage of development where we can do bugfix-only releases of older major versions of the library. There's really no point chasing down a bug in an outdated version of a rapidly evolving software project if the bug does not exist in the latest release

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following some investigation, the issue is solved in *pyarrow 0.7.0* according to this [Jira issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-1437) and more precisely [this commit](https://github.com/apache/arrow/commit/b36aab5abfa7b398c9b307930a9f1ba4c9dc08c8) using the same snippet as in the question, now instead of crashing the interpreter we obtain the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "table.pxi", line 755, in pyarrow.lib.Table.from_pandas
File "C:\Temp\tt\Tools\Anaconda3.4.3.1\envs\GMF_test3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\pandas_compat.py", line 227, in dataframe_to_arrays
    col, type=type, timestamps_to_ms=timestamps_to_ms
File "array.pxi", line 225, in pyarrow.lib.Array.from_pandas
File "error.pxi", line 77, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Error converting from Python objects to Int64: Got Python object of type bool but can only handle these ty
pes: integer
```

One possibility to workaround the issue is when you master your data, to convert the column with mixed dtypes when the exception occurs, like the following (and probably log the exception as it is not a common mistake):

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

data = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, True], 'b': [1, 2]})


def convert_type_if_needed(type_to_select, df, col_name):
    types = []
    for i in df[col_name]:
        types.append(type(i))
    if type_to_select in types:
        return df.astype({col_name: type_to_select})
    else:
        raise TypeError(str(type_to_select) + " is not in the dataframe, conversion impossible")


try:
    table = pa.Table.from_pandas(data)
except pa.lib.ArrowInvalid as e:
    logger.warning(e)
    data = convert_type_if_needed(int, data, 'a')
    table = pa.Table.from_pandas(data)

print(table)
```

Which finally yields:

```
pyarrow.Table
Error converting from Python objects to Int64: Got Python object of type bool but can only handle these types: integer
a: int32
b: int64
__index_level_0__: int64
metadata
--------
{b'pandas': b'{"columns": [{"name": "a", "numpy_type": "int32", "pandas_type":'
            b' "int32", "metadata": null}, {"name": "b", "numpy_type": "int64"'
            b', "pandas_type": "int64", "metadata": null}, {"name": "__index_l'
            b'evel_0__", "numpy_type": "int64", "pandas_type": "int64", "metad'
            b'ata": null}], "index_columns": ["__index_level_0__"], "pandas_ve'
            b'rsion": "0.20.3"}'}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question? Since it only leads to a new error.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Doesn't it? Isn't a nice error message much more useful (and "catchable") than a crash of the interpreter? (By the way, **now** it leads to an error, before it lead to a **crash**)

Comment: I'd believe the ideal answer would suggest a solution/improvement/workaround in addition...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Good idea, although in my particular case, the exception definitely needs to be raised and the execution stopped, I tried to imagine a workaround in an edit to the above answer